# Average without outliers

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to find the avarage without outliers using elasticsearch query? Im still using elasticsearch 1.7

Another option is to find the avarage of all the values below the 95th percentile

Answer (score -1):

Elasticsearch uses [aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html) to create average, sum, max and min values:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "avg_grade" : { "avg" : { "field" : "grade" } }
    }
}
```

Please read the documentation about aggregations, this will be https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html

Comment: Will it remove outliers?

Comment: please you need to more specific or post examples about your needs, i just tried to help and you gave me a negativation.

Comment: I didnt :) im really asking